# Нужно отсортировать введенные числа от меньшего к большему, что не так?

Tags: python

```
massiv = {}
razm = int(input("Введите количество массивов = "))
dict = {}

for i in range(razm):
    massiv[i] = input("Элементы[" + str(i) + "] = ")
    dict[massiv[i]] = len(massiv[i])

dict = sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
for i in range(razm): 
    print(dict[i][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы имели ввиду это:

**Для python 3.6 и новее**

```py
razm = int(input("Введите количество массивов: "))

numbers = list()
for massiv in range(razm):
    for i in input(f"Введите числа в массиве №{massiv + 1} через пробел: ").split():
        numbers.append(i)
numbers.sort()

print("Отсортированные числа в порядке возрастания:")
for number in numbers:
    print(number)
```

**Для остальных случаев**

```py
razm = int(input("Введите количество массивов: "))

numbers = list()
for massiv in range(razm):
    for i in input("Введите числа в массиве №{} через пробел: ".format(massiv + 1)).split():
        numbers.append(i)
numbers.sort()

print("Отсортированные числа в порядке возрастания:")
for number in numbers:
    print(number)
```

P.s.: не используйте слово "dict" как имя переменной - оно уже зарезервированно. И не совсем ясно зачем нужно множество massiv, если потом оно становится элементом словаря. Хотя я вас понимаю, вы писали этот алгоритм как могли - просто учтите на будущее и удачи!

Comment: не выходит

мне нужно что бы когда пользователь вводил колво массивов (2), например

потом вводил числа через пробел
например, элементы в массиве 1  = 9 2 3
потом в массиве 2 = 3 2 7
 и оно выдавало

2 3 9
2 3 7

Comment: @АннаАннна исправил, проверьте

Answer (score 0):

Возможно так

```
numbers = int(input("Введите количество массивов: "))

arrays = []

for array_number in range(1,numbers + 1):
    current_array = [int(item) for item in input("Введите массив {} :".format(array_number)).split()]
    current_array.sort()
    arrays += current_array

for array in arrays:
    print(array, end = ' ')
```